# Не работает getline при использовании контейнера vector

Tags: stl, c, c++

Написал небольшую программку, а-ля "телефонная книга" на Си. Сейчас разбираюсь с STL-контейнерами и вот столкнулся с тем, что при использовании не работает ф-ия getline. 
Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int n = 10;

struct Entry
{
    string name;
    int ID;
};

int cin_entry(vector<Entry> &v);
int print_entry(vector<Entry> &v);

int main()
{
    vector<Entry> phone_book(n);
    cin_entry(phone_book);
    cout << endl;
    print_entry(phone_book);
}

int cin_entry(vector<Entry> &v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        //getline(cin, v[i].name);
        cin >> v[i].name;
        cin >> v[i].ID;
    }
}

int print_entry(vector<Entry> &v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << v[i].name << " " << v[i].ID << endl;
    }
}
```

В чем проблема? Почему не работает getline, а cin работает? И как мне тогда (если getline не пашет), что бы я мог в одну строку ввести несколько слов через пробел?

Comment: @Hamsternik странно, а у меня работает. Правда для Вашей программы формат входного файла несколько странный:

    Наме Наме Намович
    1НеНаме Ненаме Ненамович
    2...

Поскольку после `cin >> v[i].ID;` во входном буфере конец строки (тут это вопрос часто поднимается, вот совсем недавно было). Если хотите делить строки, делайте getline после чтения ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Hamsternik](/users/13249/hamsternik), если это ещё актуально, то ответ на ваш вопрос приблизительно такой:

---

действительно, `operator>>` оставляет в входном потоке символ новой строки `'\n'`, поэтому следующий вызов `getline(cin, v[i].name);` опускается.

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы всё работало как надо, то вам необходимо очищать входной поток от этого символа:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

А вообще, везде советуют не применять в связке `operator>>` и `getline()` из-за подобных вещей, пробуйте подобрать другие варианты ввода.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Hamsternik](/users/13249/hamsternik)](/users/13249/hamsternik), опять же если еще актуально.

Если не лениться, то лучше всего читать входной файл по строкам, а потом уже разбирать прочитанную строку.

Например, Ваша программа ввода телефонной книги может выглядеть так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;
#define SPACES " \t"

struct Entry {
  unsigned long long num;  // ведь на самом деле телефонные номера м.б. длинными
  string text;
};

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  Entry in;
  vector<Entry> v(1);
  string str;

  while (cout << "Enter Number Text: ", getline(cin, str)) {
    // анализ введенных данных
    if (str.find_first_not_of(SPACES) == string::npos)
      continue;  // просто ничего не ввели

    // дальше часть на Си, т.к. нормальное чтение числа из строки появилось только в С++11
    char *t;
    in.num = strtoull(str.c_str(), &t, 10);
    if (t == str.c_str() || !isspace(*t) || errno == ERANGE || 
        !t[strspn(t, SPACES)]) { // !t[strspn(...)] это проверка, что после номера есть текст
      errno = 0;
      cout << "Bad data\n"; 
      continue;
    }

    // уберем лидирующие пробелы из запоминаемого текста одной строкой
    in.text = t + strspn(t, SPACES);  // и здесь использовать Си короче
    v.push_back(in);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    cout << v[i].num << ": " << v[i].text << '\n';

}
```